# JPlayer controls are jumbled up in IE - works fine in all other browsers

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, jplayer

Has anyone come across this before?

Examples here:

[Page 2](http://soundshelter.net/playlist.php)

(excuse the soundclips - just demo ones of some atrocious music)

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

hilarious music!

try changing your swfpath constructor option to

`swfPath: "js"`

Comment: Terrible isnt it haha. Sorry that didn't work...any other ideas? Thanks for helping